# How to translate Arabic/Persian numbers to english using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, encoding, localization, type-conversion, arabic

How can I convert some string that has Arabic/Persian number to English ?

Like if I have :

```
str1 = "١۲١۲"
str2 = "12١۲"
str3 = "some string that contains persian digits like ١۲"
```

Is there any function to encode it to english, and if the string contain such number to convert it like end results will be :

```
str1 = "1212"
str2 = "1212"
str3 = "some string that contains persian digits like 12"
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that's encoding, more like translation since those are the arabic representation of the numbers 1 and 2.

Comment: This is not encoding. For this, you need a library that understands Arabic numbers, not just the characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For these one on one transformations the [tr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-tr)-method is very convenient and fast. It has a mutating counterpart in `tr!`

```
#encoding: utf-8

str1 = "١۲١۲"
str2 = "12١۲"
str3 = "some string that contains persian digits like ١۲"

[str1, str2, str3].each{|str| str.tr!('۰١۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹','0123456789')}

p str1, str2, str3
#"1212"
#"1212"
#"some string that contains persian digits like 12"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this is not encoding but translation and assuming your problem limits to only those numbers (0-9), you could write a simple 1-to-1 mapping from arabic to english, something like this:

```
  arabic_to_english = {
  '٩' => 9,
  '٨' => 8,
  '٧' => 7,
  '٦' => 6,
  '٥' => 5,
  '٤' => 4,
  '٣' => 3,
  '٢' => 2,
  '١' => 1,
  '٠' => 0
}
```

And you just call the hash whenever needed:

```
   arabic_to_english['٧']
```

Better if you extract this into a function of course.

Comment: 1 upto 9 are upside down, '٩' => 9 etc.

Comment: Sorry about that, corrected now. Thanks for pointing that out.